Self Hosted AzureDevOps agent disconnection after few mins of inactivity with error "Socket Error: ConnectionReset"
I'm running AzureDevOps Pipeline on GCP VM.
I have successfully attached one of the GCP VMs as a Self-Hosted agent to AzureDevOps to provision resources in GCP.
I can run all the pipelines successfully and provision resources in GCP, as expected.
However, after a few minutes of idle time, the "Self Hosted Agent (GCP VM)" is showing offline.
To bring the agent online, I need to login to the GCP VM and run ./run.sh & command to allow the agent to run again.
From Azure agent logs, the error I see is Socket Error: ConnectionReset full logs below for reference, please note, few values are redacted
[2024-11-25 14:16:52Z INFO JobDispatcher] Worker finished for job 555555-55555-55555-5555-555555. Code: 102
[2024-11-25 14:16:52Z INFO JobDispatcher] finish job request for job 555555-55555-55555-5555-555555 with result: Failed
[2024-11-25 14:16:52Z INFO Terminal] WRITE LINE: 2024-11-25 14:16:52Z: Job datadog_agent_install completed with result: Failed
[2024-11-25 14:16:52Z INFO JobDispatcher] Stop renew job request for job 555555-55555-55555-5555-555555.
[2024-11-25 14:16:52Z INFO JobDispatcher] job renew has been canceled, stop renew job request 99020.
[2024-11-25 14:16:52Z INFO JobNotification] Entering JobCompleted Notification
[2024-11-25 14:16:52Z INFO JobNotification] Entering EndMonitor
[2024-11-25 14:17:15Z INFO MessageListener] Sleeping for 10.247 seconds before retrying.
[2024-11-25 14:33:54Z INFO MessageListener] Sent GetAgentMessage to keep alive agent 5214, session '11111111-bbbb-cccc-dddd-eeeeeeeeeeee'.
[2024-11-25 14:34:20Z INFO MessageListener] Sleeping for 5.217 seconds before retrying.
[2024-11-25 14:35:14Z INFO MessageListener] Sent GetAgentMessage to keep alive agent 5214, session '11111111-bbbb-cccc-dddd-eeeeeeeeeeee'.
[2024-11-25 14:35:15Z INFO MessageListener] Sleeping for 7.191 seconds before retrying.
[2024-11-25 14:35:44Z INFO MessageListener] Sent GetAgentMessage to keep alive agent 5214, session '11111111-bbbb-cccc-dddd-eeeeeeeeeeee'.
[2024-11-25 14:36:13Z INFO MessageListener] Sleeping for 9.866 seconds before retrying.
[2024-11-25 14:37:04Z INFO MessageListener] Sent GetAgentMessage to keep alive agent 5214, session '11111111-bbbb-cccc-dddd-eeeeeeeeeeee'.
[2024-11-25 14:37:13Z INFO MessageListener] Sleeping for 14.743 seconds before retrying.
[2024-11-25 14:38:18Z INFO MessageListener] Sleeping for 13.426 seconds before retrying.
[2024-11-25 14:38:25Z INFO MessageListener] Sent GetAgentMessage to keep alive agent 5214, session '11111111-bbbb-cccc-dddd-eeeeeeeeeeee'.
[2024-11-25 14:38:31Z WARN VisualStudioServices] Attempt 1 of GET request to https://<dns-url>/<organization>/_apis/distributedtask/pools/275/messages failed (Socket Error: ConnectionReset). The operation will be retried in 11.0614112 seconds.
[2024-11-25 14:39:32Z INFO MessageListener] Sleeping for 13.085 seconds before retrying.
[2024-11-25 14:39:45Z INFO MessageListener] Sent GetAgentMessage to keep alive agent 5214, session '11111111-bbbb-cccc-dddd-eeeeeeeeeeee'.
[2024-11-25 14:40:35Z INFO MessageListener] Sleeping for 11.614 seconds before retrying.
[2024-11-25 14:41:05Z INFO MessageListener] Sent GetAgentMessage to keep alive agent 5214, session '11111111-bbbb-cccc-dddd-eeeeeeeeeeee'.
[2024-11-25 14:41:37Z INFO MessageListener] Sleeping for 6.738 seconds before retrying.
[2024-11-25 14:41:44Z INFO MessageListener] Sleeping for 13.28 seconds before retrying.
[2024-11-25 14:42:25Z INFO MessageListener] Sent GetAgentMessage to keep alive agent 5214, session '11111111-bbbb-cccc-dddd-eeeeeeeeeeee'.
[2024-11-25 14:42:48Z INFO MessageListener] Sleeping for 10.344 seconds before retrying.

The command I have used for registering the Self-hosted agent (GCP VM)
<<PATH>>/config.sh --replace --work work --acceptTeeEula --url https://<domain>/<org>/ --auth pat --token <<PAT-TOKEN>> --agent <my-agent> --pool <my-agent-pool> && <<PATH>>/run.sh
and then:
<<PATH>>/run.sh &
As far as registration is concerned I do not see the problem, since we are successfully able to run the jobs. The only problem is, the agent becomes offline, after a few mins (may be 15-25 mins) of inactivity.
To rule out if there is any issue with the agent, I have used a docker container image and successfully added this container as a Self-Hosted agent. Even in this case, I was able to run all the pipelines successfully, but again after a few mins (may be 15-25 mins) of inactivity the agent went offline. Also, googled a few other solutions, but couldn't find the answer.
GCP VM Instance details
NAME="CentOS Stream"
VERSION="9"
ID="centos"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="9"
PLATFORM_ID="platform:el9"
PRETTY_NAME="CentOS Stream 9"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
LOGO="fedora-logo-icon"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:centos:centos:9"
HOME_URL="https://centos.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://issues.redhat.com/"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="Red Hat Enterprise Linux 9"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="CentOS Stream"

Request for help to sort the issue, so that Self-Hosted agent should stay online without getting disconnected

Below solution helped me, need to run the agent as a service, so it automatically starts with the VM and keeps running in the background:
A) Linux VM:

Navigate to the agent's directory on the GCP VM.
Configure the agent to run as a service:

sudo ./svc.sh install
sudo ./svc.sh start


Verify the service is running:
sudo systemctl status

B) Windows VM:

Open a Command Prompt or PowerShell as an Administrator.
Navigate to the agent directory
Install the agent as service by running the following command in the agent directory:

.\svc.cmd install
.\svc.cmd start


Open the Services app on your Windows machine (search for services.msc).
Look for a service named something like vsts.agent....
Ensure the service status is Running.

